# Bayesian filtration technique for physics based model tuning

Tags: python, bayesian, kalman-filter, processmodel

I am new to Bayesian filtration techniques. It will be helpful, if you guide me on easy explainable terms the above concept.
I am seeking how to use Bayesian Filtration techniques for physics based model tuning.
Thanks in anticipation

Comment: please post part of your code and the particular problem in the code your experiencing